# Convert from hex64 to base 64 String

Tags: java, encoding, base64

My input hex is

```
C30A010000003602000F73B32F9ECA00E9F2F2E9
```

I need to convert it to the following base 64 encoded String:

```
wwoBAAAANgIAD3OzL57KAOny8uk=
```

I can simulate this transformation on this site: http://www.asciitohex.com/ but I cant seem to get this transformation working in Java using the various base64 encoder Utils that are suggested on this site and other places on the web. For example,

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String args[]) throws DecoderException {

    String hexString = "C30A010000003602000F73B32F9ECA00E9F2F2E9";

    String output = new String(Base64.encodeBase64String(hexString.getBytes()));

    System.out.println(output);

}
```

However the output for this is something different:

```
QzMwQTAxMDAwMDAwMzYwMjAwMEY3M0IzMkY5RUNBMDBFOUYyRjJFOQ==
```

Can anyone suggest how to get this transformation working successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `hexString.getBytes()` doesn't do what you expect it to. It's just encoding the string as a byte sequence in your platform default encoding - it's got nothing to do with hex.

You need to decode from hex to `byte[]` to start with. Additionally, you don't need to call the `String` constructor with another string. As you're already using Apache Commons Codec, it makes sense to use the [`Hex`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class for the decoding. I would also separate out the steps for clarity:

```
String hexString = "C30A010000003602000F73B32F9ECA00E9F2F2E9";
byte[] rawData = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray());
String output = Base64.encodeBase64String(rawData);
```